# How to show stored data in a scrollview of another activity using database?

Tags: android, android-intent, scrollview, android-sqlite

I'm here new developer. I'm trying to use database. I have shown data in same activity using

```
spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
loadtospinner();

public void loadtospinner() {

    Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME));
        al.add(name);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1, al);

    spn.setAdapter(aa1);

    // closing database
    SQLcon.close();

}
```

And now I want to show data in a scrollview of a new activity. can anyone tell me what and how I should do now.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: I want to show stored data in a scrollview of another class.